# Migrate from Hybrid Azure AD to Full Cloud

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, hybrid

Currently setup with a hybrid Azure AD. Most of our devices are still joined to the local AD servers, with a few newer devices having been onboarded via Azure AD instead of local AD.

I've been searching for a while now but there doesn't seem to be many good resources for the move away from hybrid, other then: Manually unjoin and rejoin every device.

Hoping that I am missing something here and there is a way to do this via a script or other means?

Any suggestions or links are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

***AFAIK**, currently there is no way to **automate** migrating from hybrid Azure AD devices to Full cloud.*

> **You cannot change a hybrid joined device to full cloud without first
> removing from the domain and joining to Azure.**

You can find the similar scenario in this [**Microsoft Q&A by Sander Berkouwer**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/42917/how-to-migrate-hybrid-azure-ad-to-full-azure-ad.html) that confirms the above.

You have to manually unjoin and rejoin every device. Before removing the devices, make sure to check the state of them using `dsregcmd /status`.

[image]

If **`DomainJoined`** is 'YES', unjoin the devices by following the below steps:

- Make sure to turn off automatic registration before removing hybrid Azure AD devices.
- Run command prompt as an **administrator** and execute the below command as a script to unjoin several devices in bulk: `dsregcmd.exe /debug /leave`

Please check the below **links** that can give you some pointers.

[Migration from Hybrid to AAD by sikumars-msft - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/500067/migration-from-hybrid-to-aad.html)

[Convert hybrid AAD devices to full AAD joined - Azure Forum (spiceworks.com)](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2318429-convert-hybrid-aad-devices-to-full-aad-joined)